# How can I get the description of the news?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I get the paragraph between tags (

İstinye Üniversitesi Mühendislik Fakültesi öğrencileri Sektörle İşbirliği Ofisi’nin düzenlediği “Mentörün CEO Olsun” programı kapsamında Albayrak Holding bünyesindeki TÜMOSAN  (Türk Motor Sanayi) firmasını ziyaret ettiler. Ziyarette öğrencilerimize Makine Mühendisliği Bölüm Başkanımız Öğr. Üyesi Dr. Barış Doğru ve Sektörle İşbirliği Ofisi Koordinatörü Öğr. Gör. Şule Kılıçarslan rehberlik ettiler. TÜMOSAN firmasından Motor Teknolojileri Müdürü Dr. Enishan Özcan ve Motor Tasarım Şefi Dr. Alen Murat Kuyumcu’nun firma tanıtımı ve güncel motor ve aktarma organları teknolojileri hakkında bilgi verilmesi ile devam eden gezide öğrencilerimiz motor atölyesi, elektronik atölyesi ve çalışma ofislerinde yapılan AR-GE faaliyetlerine takip etme fırsatı buldular. Başta traktör ve savunma sanayinde kullanılan bir çok motorun üretimini yerli ve milli sermaye ile gerçekleştiren TÜMOSAN’a ait diğer zirai ekipman, forklift ve jeneratör gruplarına ait farklı bir çok motor ve aktarma organı ekipmanının atölye ortamında detaylı incelemesi gerçekleştirildi. Öğrencilerimizin mezun olmadan önce eksik yönlerini geliştirebilecekleri, mezun olduktan sonra da iş hayatına başarılı bir giriş yapmalarını hedefleyen “Mentörün CEO Olsun” programı çerçevesinde TÜMOSAN mentörlerimizin firmanın misyonu, vizyonu, çalışma stratejisi, staj ve iş imkanları, günümüz motor teknolojisinin gerek ticari gerekse savunma sanayi açısından duyduğu mühendislik ihtiyaçlarının öğrencilerimize aktarıldığı firma gezimiz benzer seminer, ders ve teknik gezilerin yakın gelecekte devam etmesi ve işbirliğinin sürdürülmesi temennisi ile tamamlandı.

) ?

```
</div>
<div class="main-content-wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="main-content col-md-12">
<div class="region region-content">
<div class="block block-system block-system-main-block" id="block-isu-content">
<article class="node node--type-news node--view-mode-full" role="article">
<div class="node__content">
<div class="field field--name-field-paragraf field--type-entity-reference-revisions field--label-hidden field__items">
<div class="field__item">
<div class="paragraph paragraph--type--prg-standard paragraph--view-mode--default">
<div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field__item"><p>İstinye Üniversitesi Mühendislik Fakültesi öğrencileri Sektörle İşbirliği Ofisi’nin düzenlediği “Mentörün CEO Olsun” programı kapsamında Albayrak Holding bünyesindeki TÜMOSAN  (Türk Motor Sanayi) firmasını ziyaret ettiler. Ziyarette öğrencilerimize Makine Mühendisliği Bölüm Başkanımız Öğr. Üyesi Dr. Barış Doğru ve Sektörle İşbirliği Ofisi Koordinatörü Öğr. Gör. Şule Kılıçarslan rehberlik ettiler. TÜMOSAN firmasından Motor Teknolojileri Müdürü Dr. Enishan Özcan ve Motor Tasarım Şefi Dr. Alen Murat Kuyumcu’nun firma tanıtımı ve güncel motor ve aktarma organları teknolojileri hakkında bilgi verilmesi ile devam eden gezide öğrencilerimiz motor atölyesi, elektronik atölyesi ve çalışma ofislerinde yapılan AR-GE faaliyetlerine takip etme fırsatı buldular. Başta traktör ve savunma sanayinde kullanılan bir çok motorun üretimini yerli ve milli sermaye ile gerçekleştiren TÜMOSAN’a ait diğer zirai ekipman, forklift ve jeneratör gruplarına ait farklı bir çok motor ve aktarma organı ekipmanının atölye ortamında detaylı incelemesi gerçekleştirildi. Öğrencilerimizin mezun olmadan önce eksik yönlerini geliştirebilecekleri, mezun olduktan sonra da iş hayatına başarılı bir giriş yapmalarını hedefleyen “Mentörün CEO Olsun” programı çerçevesinde TÜMOSAN mentörlerimizin firmanın misyonu, vizyonu, çalışma stratejisi, staj ve iş imkanları, günümüz motor teknolojisinin gerek ticari gerekse savunma sanayi açısından duyduğu mühendislik ihtiyaçlarının öğrencilerimize aktarıldığı firma gezimiz benzer seminer, ders ve teknik gezilerin yakın gelecekte devam etmesi ve işbirliğinin sürdürülmesi temennisi ile tamamlandı.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
g=urlopen("https://muhendislik.istinye.edu.tr/tr/haberler/muhendislik-fakultesi-ogrencileri-tumosan-teknik-gezisine-katildi")
soup2=BeautifulSoup(g.read(),"html.parser")
deneme=soup2.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field__item"})
```

output;

```
[<div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field__item"><p>İstinye Üniversitesi Mühendislik Fakültesi öğrencileri Sektörle İşbirliği Ofisi’nin düzenlediği “Mentörün CEO Olsun” programı kapsamında Albayrak Holding bünyesindeki TÜMOSAN  (Türk Motor Sanayi) firmasını ziyaret ettiler. Ziyarette öğrencilerimize Makine Mühendisliği Bölüm Başkanımız Öğr. Üyesi Dr. Barış Doğru ve Sektörle İşbirliği Ofisi Koordinatörü Öğr. Gör. Şule Kılıçarslan rehberlik ettiler. TÜMOSAN firmasından Motor Teknolojileri Müdürü Dr. Enishan Özcan ve Motor Tasarım Şefi Dr. Alen Murat Kuyumcu’nun firma tanıtımı ve güncel motor ve aktarma organları teknolojileri hakkında bilgi verilmesi ile devam eden gezide öğrencilerimiz motor atölyesi, elektronik atölyesi ve çalışma ofislerinde yapılan AR-GE faaliyetlerine takip etme fırsatı buldular. Başta traktör ve savunma sanayinde kullanılan bir çok motorun üretimini yerli ve milli sermaye ile gerçekleştiren TÜMOSAN’a ait diğer zirai ekipman, forklift ve jeneratör gruplarına ait farklı bir çok motor ve aktarma organı ekipmanının atölye ortamında detaylı incelemesi gerçekleştirildi. Öğrencilerimizin mezun olmadan önce eksik yönlerini geliştirebilecekleri, mezun olduktan sonra da iş hayatına başarılı bir giriş yapmalarını hedefleyen “Mentörün CEO Olsun” programı çerçevesinde TÜMOSAN mentörlerimizin firmanın misyonu, vizyonu, çalışma stratejisi, staj ve iş imkanları, günümüz motor teknolojisinin gerek ticari gerekse savunma sanayi açısından duyduğu mühendislik ihtiyaçlarının öğrencilerimize aktarıldığı firma gezimiz benzer seminer, ders ve teknik gezilerin yakın gelecekte devam etmesi ve işbirliğinin sürdürülmesi temennisi ile tamamlandı.</p>
</div>]
```

Comment: `deneme[0].text`

Comment: you have to try an generalize your problem so that other people might find it useful in the future. Right now you're asking SO to work for you!

Comment: Is this a question in an other language or is this just an unclear English question? Is `<p>long text</p>` not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
html='''<div class="main-content-wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="main-content col-md-12">
<div class="region region-content">
<div class="block block-system block-system-main-block" id="block-isu-content">
<article class="node node--type-news node--view-mode-full" role="article">
<div class="node__content">
<div class="field field--name-field-paragraf field--type-entity-reference-revisions field--label-hidden field__items">
<div class="field__item">
<div class="paragraph paragraph--type--prg-standard paragraph--view-mode--default">
<div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field__item"><p>İstinye Üniversitesi Mühendislik Fakültesi öğrencileri Sektörle İşbirliği Ofisi’nin düzenlediği “Mentörün CEO Olsun” programı kapsamında Albayrak Holding bünyesindeki TÜMOSAN  (Türk Motor Sanayi) firmasını ziyaret ettiler. Ziyarette öğrencilerimize Makine Mühendisliği Bölüm Başkanımız Öğr. Üyesi Dr. Barış Doğru ve Sektörle İşbirliği Ofisi Koordinatörü Öğr. Gör. Şule Kılıçarslan rehberlik ettiler. TÜMOSAN firmasından Motor Teknolojileri Müdürü Dr. Enishan Özcan ve Motor Tasarım Şefi Dr. Alen Murat Kuyumcu’nun firma tanıtımı ve güncel motor ve aktarma organları teknolojileri hakkında bilgi verilmesi ile devam eden gezide öğrencilerimiz motor atölyesi, elektronik atölyesi ve çalışma ofislerinde yapılan AR-GE faaliyetlerine takip etme fırsatı buldular. Başta traktör ve savunma sanayinde kullanılan bir çok motorun üretimini yerli ve milli sermaye ile gerçekleştiren TÜMOSAN’a ait diğer zirai ekipman, forklift ve jeneratör gruplarına ait farklı bir çok motor ve aktarma organı ekipmanının atölye ortamında detaylı incelemesi gerçekleştirildi. Öğrencilerimizin mezun olmadan önce eksik yönlerini geliştirebilecekleri, mezun olduktan sonra da iş hayatına başarılı bir giriş yapmalarını hedefleyen “Mentörün CEO Olsun” programı çerçevesinde TÜMOSAN mentörlerimizin firmanın misyonu, vizyonu, çalışma stratejisi, staj ve iş imkanları, günümüz motor teknolojisinin gerek ticari gerekse savunma sanayi açısından duyduğu mühendislik ihtiyaçlarının öğrencilerimize aktarıldığı firma gezimiz benzer seminer, ders ve teknik gezilerin yakın gelecekte devam etmesi ve işbirliğinin sürdürülmesi temennisi ile tamamlandı.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
items=soup.find_all('div', class_='clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field__item')
for item in items:
 print(item.text)
```

**EDITED**

You can use selenium and Beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('file/path/chrome driver')
driver.get("https://muhendislik.istinye.edu.tr/tr/haberler/muhendislik-fakultesi-ogrencileri-tumosan-teknik-gezisine-katildi")
html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
items=soup.find_all('div', class_='clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field__item')
for item in items:
 print(item.text)
```

You can download chrome driver from following link : [chrome driver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Comment: is turning empty.

Comment: It is giving me output in the console.In that case you have to share url?

Comment: https://muhendislik.istinye.edu.tr/tr/haberler/muhendislik-fakultesi-ogrencileri-tumosan-teknik-gezisine-katildi

Comment: Its giving me exception with your url ` Max retries exceeded with` that why you are not able to get the value using my code.Try later it will return you the value

Comment: Thank you for dealing:)

Comment: However you can use selenium and beautiful soup to get the value.You need to install selenium as well need to download chrome driver.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `verify=False` to handle ssl errors

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib3; urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
r = requests.get('https://muhendislik.istinye.edu.tr/tr/haberler/muhendislik-fakultesi-ogrencileri-tumosan-teknik-gezisine-katildi', headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}, verify = False)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.field--type-text-long').text)
```